# How can I retrieve the value of an attribute supported by Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle9i, tablespace, flashback

1. Tablespace FlashBack

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TS_Physical
    DATAFILE
        '\physical_df.dbf'
            SIZE 1024000
            AUTOEXTEND OFF
    BLOCKSIZE 8192
    LOGGING
    FORCE LOGGING
    ONLINE
    EXTENT MANAGEMENT
        LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
    SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO
    FLASHBACK ON;
```

I looked up USER_TABLESPACES and DBA_TABLESPACES that store tablespace information, but there is no entry called FlashBack.

```sql
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLESPACES;
SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLESPACES;
```

I obviously have flashback on. How can I query whether the tablespace is using flashback or not?

If it is an item that cannot be viewed, please share a link to the related document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[V$TABLESPACE.FLASHBACK_ON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-TABLESPACE.html)

```
SQL> select name,flashback_on from v$tablespace;

NAME                           FLASHBACK_ON
------------------------------ ------------
SYSTEM                         YES
SYSAUX                         YES
UNDOTBS1                       YES
TEMP                           YES
USERS                          YES
```

Comment: The flashback_on keyword is not known in 9i.

Comment: _"The flashback_on keyword is not known in 9i"_  Flashback was not available in 9i. Your CREATE TABLESPACE statement should have thrown an error when executed in 9i.  And FWIW, 9i has been out of support since July 2010 - over 21 years ago.